# Where is android syncing my photo's to?

Tags: sync, google-drive

I just got an android and have it synced to my google account, the problem is that it is syncing my photo's to I don't know where on my google account, which is very bad because I take pictures of sensitive documents for my job. Every once in a while I get a notice that these synced photos are ready to share. I've looked in drive and don't see them, I've looked on plus and only see the ones I've said it's ok to share, but it's syncing them somewhere online which in the case of these particular articles is illegal no mater how "Secure" this may be.  So where the heck are these going?

Comment: What version of android are you running and on what phone?

Comment: Ice cream sandwhich, LG l9

Comment: Also, what is the exact message in your notification? For example, my Galaxy Note 2 says "Google+ Auto-backup, x photos ready to share".

Answer (score 2):

Your Android phone may sync photos on Google +, Dropbox, Google Drive and Facebook.
 On Google + got to https://plus.google.com/photos/search/%23AutoBackup (Photos> AutoBackup), here are photos whose automatically synced through your android phone. [How to Enable/ Disable auto sync on Android](http://www.nkjskj.com/android/google-plus-instant-upload-on-android-enabledisable/)

Next is Dropbox, check this article for dropbox sync enabled www.dropbox.com/help/82/en

Next is Google Drive which may auto sync your photos & data to server.

& Facebook is also sync photos in private folder in your albums folder.

But in my opinion your photos are being synced by Google + in Auto Backup section.